# terraform output Google Kubernetes cluster inggress load balancer ip

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, kubernetes-ingress

I've managed  to automate kubernetes cluster deployment with terraform. After bringing up cluster terraform also deploys my apps to cluster using provisioning (running .sh script with local-exec). I am also adding ingress to cluster and I need to get the ingress load balancer IP once it created. preferable option is terraform output.
The way I am getting it now is running this part of code at the end of my script

```
IP="$(kubectl get ingress appname --no-headers | awk '{print $3}')"
echo "Load Balancer IP $IP"
```

However this one has its issues, I need to add sleep before running this command to be sure that the IP is already assigned. and I can't be sure the added sleep time is enough.
Actually need smth like these but for my ingress loadbalancer IP

```
output "google_container_cluster_endpoint" {
  value = "${google_container_cluster.k8s.endpoint}"
}

output "google_container_cluster_master_version" {
  value = "${google_container_cluster.k8s.master_version}"
}
```

Comment: Which terraform modules are you using? How are you provisioning the cluster itself?

Comment: I don't use any modules, creating kubernetes cluster using resource "google_container_cluster"

Comment: There is a [Kubernetes provider](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/kubernetes/index.html) and a matching [kubernetes_service data source](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/kubernetes/d/service.html), but I don't think there's a good way to force Terraform to wait for the load balancer to exist.

Comment: Does something like 
`output "IP" {
    value = ${kubernetes_service.load_balancer_service.load_balancer_ingress.0.ip}"
}`
not work?

Answer (score 4):

I have managed to get external ingress ip in fully declarative approach. It is based on different providers including azurerm, kubernetes, helm. I am targeting Azure Kubernetes Service, but the solution is cloud agnostic.

Solution explanation:

> Use kubernetes provider to connect cluster after ingress creation. Kubernetes provides allows reading service data like external ip.

Providers overview:

- azurerm provider is used for Azure communication

  - It is possible to create Kubernetes (K8s) via different provider,
- helm provider is used for ingress installation,

  - It is possible to create ingress using different approach,
- kubernetes provider allows me to query Load balancer service

**Short snippet**

```
provider "kubernetes" { }

provider "helm" { }

resource "helm_release" "nginx-ingress" {
  name             = "nginx-ingress"
  namespace        = "nginx-ingress"
  create_namespace = true
  repository       = "https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com"
  chart            = "nginx-ingress"

  set {
    name  = "controller.replicaCount"
    value = "2"
  }
}

data "kubernetes_service" "service_ingress" {
  metadata {
    name      = "nginx-ingress-controller"
    namespace = "nginx-ingress"
  }

  depends_on = [ helm_release.nginx-ingress ] 
}

output "ip" {
  value = data.kubernetes_service.service_ingress.load_balancer_ingress.0.ip
}
```

**Complete snippet**

```
variable "subscription_id" {
  type = string
}

variable "client_id" {
  type = string
}

variable "client_secret" {
  type = string
}

variable "tenant_id" {
  type = string
}

variable "resource_location"{
  type = string
}

terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "2.29.0"
    }

    kubernetes = {
      source = "hashicorp/kubernetes"
      version = "1.13.2"
    }

    helm = {
      source = "hashicorp/helm"
      version = "1.3.1"
    }
  }
}

provider "azurerm" {
  subscription_id = var.subscription_id
  client_id       = var.client_id
  client_secret   = var.client_secret
  tenant_id       = var.tenant_id
  features {}
}

provider "kubernetes" {
  load_config_file       = "false"
  host                   = azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks.kube_config.0.host
  client_certificate     = base64decode(azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks.kube_config.0.client_certificate)
  client_key             = base64decode(azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks.kube_config.0.client_key)
  cluster_ca_certificate = base64decode(azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks.kube_config.0.cluster_ca_certificate)
}

provider "helm" {
  kubernetes {
    load_config_file       = "false"
    host                   = azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks.kube_config.0.host
    client_certificate     = base64decode(azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks.kube_config.0.client_certificate)
    client_key             = base64decode(azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks.kube_config.0.client_key)
    cluster_ca_certificate = base64decode(azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks.kube_config.0.cluster_ca_certificate)
  }
}

data "kubernetes_service" "service_ingress" {
  metadata {
    name      = "nginx-ingress-controller"
    namespace = "nginx-ingress"
  }

  depends_on = [ helm_release.nginx-ingress ] 
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
  name     = "myapp"
  location = var.resource_location
}

resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "aks" {
  name                = "myapp"
  location            = var.resource_location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  dns_prefix          = "myapp"
  kubernetes_version  = "1.17.11"

  default_node_pool {
    name            = "default"
    node_count      = 2
    vm_size         = "Standard_B2s"
    os_disk_size_gb = 30
    type = "VirtualMachineScaleSets"
    enable_auto_scaling = false
  }

  service_principal {
    client_id     = var.client_id
    client_secret = var.client_secret
  }

  role_based_access_control {
    enabled = true
  }
}

resource "helm_release" "nginx-ingress" {
  name             = "nginx-ingress"
  namespace        = "nginx-ingress"
  create_namespace = true
  repository       = "https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com"
  chart            = "nginx-ingress"

  set {
    name  = "controller.replicaCount"
    value = "2"
  }

  set {
    name  = "controller.nodeSelector.kubernetes\\.io/os"
    value = "linux"
  }

  set {
    name  = "defaultBackend.nodeSelector.kubernetes\\.io/os"
    value = "linux"
  }
}

output "ip" {
  value = data.kubernetes_service.service_ingress.load_balancer_ingress.0.ip
}
```

Comment: Perfect! I just had to modify the `ip` output to `data.kubernetes_service.service_ingress.status[0].load_balancer[0].ingress[0].ip`

Comment: I've done the same, but setting the dependency isn't enough to force waiting for its creation, tf is just fetching it as `null` so the first `apply` is failing, and the second one successfully reads the data resource and outputs the value. Annoying. After some test with the wait resource, it seems the value isn't read at all if it is not present from the beginning.

Comment: Maybe there were some changes, however the solution was fully operational. Dependency was working fine. Does anybody have the same issue?

Comment: The reason is probably a change of behavior in helm and therefore in the `nginx` helm resource. https://github.com/helm/helm/pull/7530

Answer (score 0):

After a long Saturday, I've end up with a solution to the the problem. I was with almost the same issue, so here is my solution, surely can be improved.

I divided in two parts:

1.- I'll use local-exec to run a script that solves the problem of waiting for a valid IP in the load LoadBalancer
  2.-**Terraform**, using  **External Data Source** calls a "program" that answers in json format. My "program" is a bash script that grabs the IP. As a result, I have my desired data in a variable.

I did it this way cause I didn't know how to debug issues using **External Data Source** and I was suffering "Stranger things"

First I run the code to wait for a valid IP. Terraform calls the **local-exec**

---

```
provisioner "local-exec" {
  command = "./public-ip.sh"
  interpreter = ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
}
```

---

And this is the script I've used

---

```
#!/bin/bash
#public-ip.sh
#!/bin/bash
# Exit if any of the intermediate steps fail
set -e

function valid_ip()
{
    local  ip=$1
    local  stat=1

    if [[ $ip =~ ^[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}$ ]]; then
        OIFS=$IFS
        IFS='.'
        ip=($ip)
        IFS=$OIFS
        [[ ${ip[0]} -le 255 && ${ip[1]} -le 255 \
            && ${ip[2]} -le 255 && ${ip[3]} -le 255 ]]
        stat=$?
    fi
    return $stat
}

########################
# Grab the Public IP   #
#######################
WaitingTime=0
HaveIP=NO

echo "Let's check that LoadBalancer IP..."
MyPublicIP=$(kubectl get services --all-namespaces| grep LoadBalancer | awk '{print $5}')
valid_ip $MyPublicIP && HaveIP="OK"

until [ "$HaveIP" = "OK" -o "$WaitingTime" -ge 30 ]; do
    echo "sleeeping...."
    sleep 10
    echo "Play it again Sam..."
    MyPublicIP=$(kubectl get services --all-namespaces| grep LoadBalancer | awk '{print $5}')
    #if valid_ip $MyPublicIP; then echo "We got the IP"; HaveIP=YES ;else stat='Still without IP'; fi
    #if valid_ip $MyPublicIP; then HaveIP="OK" ; fi
    valid_ip $MyPublicIP && HaveIP="OK"
    #if valid_ip $MyPublicIP; then HaveIP="OK" ; fi
    WaitingTime=$((WaitingTime+1))
    echo $WaitingTime
done
if [ "$HaveIP" = "OK" ]; then echo  An the public IP is... $MyPublicIP; else echo "WT_ has happened now!!!"; fi
```

---

After I know I have the IP ready. I've just needed to grab it. Pay attention to the **depends_on** that controls I'll grab my data once my resource (google_container_cluster.tests) it's been created, and not whenever he wants. Test it. It's tricky...

---

```
data "external" "insights-public-ip" {
  program = ["sh", "test-jq.sh" ]
  depends_on = ["google_container_cluster.tests"]
}

output "insights-public-ip" {
  value = "${data.external.insights-public-ip.result}"
}
```

---

And this is **test-jq.sh** (test cause is the first time I've used :S), the script I'm calling to print out in json format the data.

---

```
#!/bin/bash
#test-jq.sh
set -e
MyPublicIP=$(kubectl get services --all-namespaces | grep insights | grep LoadBalancer | awk '{print $5}')
jq -n --arg foobaz "$MyPublicIP" '{"extvar":$foobaz}'
```

---

Hope it helps. At least I've resolved my stuff. 
[image]

Comment: Nice one. It doesn't resolve my issue, coz the main reason I wanted to get this with output is not to have to run shell script. My current configuration also uses shell script to get the Load Balancer IP. however if you want to get the output of the shell script as variable, no need to use external data, you can use TF_VARNAME to define terraform variable from shell.

Comment: Another method to get load balancer IP as output var is to use this terraform module ( https://github.com/sl1pm4t/terraform-provider-kubernetes ) to deploy ingress as a separate terraform resource and the get the load balancer IP address as its output. however your workaround also looks fine if there is no restriction to use shell script.

Answer (score 0):

This could be done, Using only kubectl in this way:

```
#!/bin/bash

while true;
do
  kubectl get svc -n istio-system istio-ingressgateway -o jsonpath='{"{\"ip\": "}{"\""}{.status.loadBalancer.ingress[0].ip}{"\"}"}' | grep -E -o "([0-9]{1,3}[\.]){3}[0-9]{1,3}" >/dev/null

  if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
      kubectl get svc -n istio-system istio-ingressgateway -o jsonpath='{"{\"ip\": "}{"\""}{.status.loadBalancer.ingress[0].ip}{"\"}"}'
      exit 0
  fi
done
```

Now you could the script your external data resource as follow:

```
data "external" "external-public-ip" {
  program = ["sh", "get-ip.sh" ]
  depends_on = [kubernetes_service.foo]
}

output "external-public-ip" {
  value = "${data.external.external-public-ip.result}"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Slightly modified version of already answered above -

Create the service:

```
resource "kubernetes_service" "service" {
  metadata {
    name      = var.service_name
    namespace = var.deployment_namespace
  }
   ...
}
```

Data source for the service created:

```
data "kubernetes_service" "service_ingress" {
  metadata {
    name      = var.service_name
    namespace = var.deployment_namespace
  }
  depends_on = [kubernetes_service.service]
}
```

Output the IP:

```
output "gke_deployment_lb_ip" {
  value       = data.kubernetes_service.service_ingress.status[0].load_balancer[0].ingress[0].ip
  description = "Deployment ALB IP"
}
```